# mysql connection issue for 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql

When I used 127.0.0.1 as host to connect to mysql server  it failed to connect

```
     Issue :  Access denied
```

When I used localhost as host to connect to mysql server it will able connect.

"127.0.0.1" is same as "localhost".

Also some where i read that mysql not able to

```
  MySQL won't auto-resolve the host name
```

What does it mean ?

Comment: Check for `bind-address=localhost` in `my.cnf` file

Answer (score 0):

localhost is special cased and uses UNIX sockets instead of TCP/IP. 127.0.0.1 doesn't get that special handling.

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html)

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the --protocol=TCP option.

If it doesn't work when you use TCP/IP then the database probably isn't listening on the network. This is generally a good thing as it enhances security (not that listening on 127.0.0.1 exposes any problems, but listening on all interfaces gives more opportunity for attacks).

If you really want to allow connections via the network, then see [skip-networking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-options.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assign rights to this ip then try: You can grant rights as per below;

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'your_user'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pass';
```

Currently only localhost has rights but local ip does not.

If still you face problem then share the error, so that other reason can be checked if any.

Note: Assign rights as per your requirement as I mentioned all privileges just an example.